# What traits lib really brings to javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, traits

Javascript already support extension so what real supplement advantages would jstraits http://code.google.com/p/jstraits/ would bring to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, Traits provides a way for unrelated classes to share code.

here's an (admittedly contrived) example: A class that draws a bouncing ball and a class that draws a happy face emoticon both need to draw a circle. They probably don't share a common super class. So, they can't inherit the circle drawing code. Traits lets you put the circle drawing code in `TShape` and say that each uses `drawCircle` from `TShape`. This leaves you with all the circle drawing code in `TShape` rather than each class having it's own implementation.

(Like I said contrived. For drawing you'd call into a common library. This is just for illustration purposes.)

Now, you can certainly do this yourself by creating a function and assigning it into each prototype. However that will become unwieldy as your codebase grows.

My rule of thumb to keep things manageable is traits can use each other however makes sense, but otherwise I try to only use traits in directly instantiable classes. Having class `A` using trait `X` and class `B` inheriting from `A` and using trait `Y` can get hairy to reason about. Especially if any renaming takes place.

Comment: " you can certainly do this yourself by creating a function and assigning it into each prototype. However that will become unwieldy as your codebase grows.": why it would be more unwieldy than to use traits since you can easily create an independent function and add it to as many prototypes as you want ?

Comment: Let's say I decide to refactor out the fill code from my `drawCircle` to a `fillShape`. With a Trait, I can add the function to the trait and it's available to all my `drawX` functions. Doing the same thing with prototypes I need to attach that to each prototype where `drawcircle` is used. Whether that object cares about fill or not.

Comment: OK thanks I'll mark as answer. Why on earth has my question being closed :(